# Check if a folder in Favorites is being displayed in the mail folder structure

Tags: vba, outlook, favorites

How do I check if the folder Favorites in Outlook is shown in the mail folder structure or make it visible?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check if `Aplication.ActiveExplore.NavigationPane.CurrentModule.NavigationModuleType` property == `0 (OlNavigationModuleType.olModuleMail)`